# Translating software

Tags: dictionary, internationalization, translation

Does anyone know an online "software dictionary"? I want to translate my small application to other languages, it doesn't have much to translate, simple words like Save, Options, Username etc. I don't trust Google Translate to do it because software language is usually different... is there some kind of software language dictionary somewhere online? It's a freeware application so I cannot afford to hire someone to translate it for me and it has only like 20 phrases to translate...

Comment: What language(s) do you need to support?

Comment: I was thinking about Spanish and Simplified Chinese...

Comment: Why would you trust some arbitrary translation software when you don't trust Google Translate? In my experience, it often has the best results. That said, for 20 sentences, I'm pretty sure you can get good human translations in a forum

Comment: I agree with Pekka.  20 phrases isn't that much.  Translation services are very cheap, typically charging $0.05(USD) or less per word.  You're probably looking at $20(USD) or less.

Comment: @Pekka Actually I wasn't looking for software rather than list of most common words what are used in programs maybe? I don't trust Google translate because for an example - in my language when I use Google translate and I want to translate the word "Save" - it translates it to a word which means something like "rescue"... which is pretty much right, but not in software context... But thank you for your forum tip!

Comment: Experience shows: Translations, no matter how simple, will always suck unless performed by someone with a firm grasp on both the source and the target language, extreme care and good knowledge of the domain (here: software).

Comment: @Badr ah I see, I misunderstood that.

Comment: Yes, *may* work. But the only ones who can tell are the ones who can translate it properly. That's the pain of localization...

Comment: Try to use Resources( resource file - String table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are few resources

Rosetta - Ubuntu translation platform https://launchpad.net/

OpenOffice.org Localization Project http://l10n.openoffice.org/

Google Translation - http://translate.google.com/#

Answer (score 0):

There is something like Microsoft Software Localization Dictionary, but I am unable to find it.

There is also a crowd-sourcing site which takes advantage of it as well as of Google Translate, but it is just a help for people that would like to translate your resources. You'll find this site on https://crowdin.com/ .
For typical words like "Open", "Save", "Close", "Back", "Next", etc. Microsoft's translation would be the best and you shouldn't have any problems localizing it by yourself...

Comment: I not looking for an existing glossary, just a tool that would enable me to create a glossary. I used a wiki in the past but it is not solving the problem.